# Django 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При попытке удалить запись из панели администратора получаю ошибку

> 'bool' object is not callable

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Серия"
        verbose_name_plural = "Серии"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, related_name='products', verbose_name="Серия", on_delete=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="Наименование")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name="Изображение товара")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Описание")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Цена")
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="В наличии", default=0)
    bought = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Количество покупок", default=0)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Доступен")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Добавлен")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Продукт"
        verbose_name_plural = "Продукты"
        index_together = [['id', 'slug']]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, verbose_name="Имя")
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    telegram_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    orders_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Сумма заказов")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Добавлен")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Пользователь"
        verbose_name_plural = "Пользователи"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders', verbose_name="Заказчик", on_delete=False)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name='Адрес', max_length=250, null=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Тип оплаты", null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Оплачено')
    send = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Отправлено')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата", null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)
        verbose_name = "Заказ"
        verbose_name_plural = "Заказы"

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Заказ: {}'.format(self.pk)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items', on_delete=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Цена', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Количество', default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.pk)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.amount
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Series, Product, User, Order, OrderItem

class SeriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name', )}

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'price', 'stock', 'available', 'bought', 'created']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'series']
    list_editable = ['price', 'stock', 'available']
    search_fields = ['name']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'mobile_number', 'orders_sum', 'created']
    list_filter = ['created']
    search_fields = ['name', 'mobile_number']

class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    raw_id_fields = ['product']

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['customer', 'paid', 'send', 'date']
    list_editable = ['paid', 'send']
    list_filter = ['paid', 'send', 'date']
    inlines = [OrderItemInline]



admin.site.register(Series, SeriesAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

**Код ошибки**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
>     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 575, in wrapper
>     return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
>     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
>     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
>     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
>     return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
>     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
>     return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1618, in changelist_view
>     response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1331, in response_action
>     response = func(self, request, queryset)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py", line 36, in delete_selected
>     queryset, opts, request.user, modeladmin.admin_site, using)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 131, in get_deleted_objects
>     collector.collect(objs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 195, in collect
>     return super().collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/yazon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 222, in collect
>     field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
> ```

Comment: Ошибку получаете когда удаляя запись из любой модели или удаляя записи только из моделей `Product`, `OrderItem` и `Order` ?

Comment: Ошибка появляется при удалении записей из любой модели

Comment: on_delete=False писать неправильно, почитайте в справке что правильно писать в on_delete

Comment: Большое спасибо за замечание! Проблема была в on_delete. После замены на on_delete = models.CASCADE всё заработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писать

```
on_delete=False
```

неправильно, [почитайте в справке](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) что правильно писать в `on_delete`:

- CASCADE удалить вместе с ссылающимися объектами
- PROTECT запретить удаление
- SET_NULL установить в нуль
- SET_DEFAULT ... значение по умолчанию
- SET(значение) ... значение в скобках
- DO_NOTHING удалить оставив битую ссылку